# Импорт JSON в SQL - ошибка IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Есть, модель

```
public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
        public int? BravoId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? parent_id { get; set; }
    }
```

Контролер

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Categories category)
        {

            string str;
            using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
            {
                str = http.GetStringAsync("https://......./export/v2/?format=json&city=msk").Result;
            }

            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(str);
            var allUid = jObject["catalog"]["categories"].Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();
            foreach (var catg in allUid)
            {

                JObject jObject2 = JObject.Parse(catg);

                var id2 = jObject2["id"].ToString();
                category.BravoId = Convert.ToInt32(id2);
                category.Name = jObject2["name"].ToString();

                if (jObject2["parent_id"] == null)
                {
                    category.parent_id = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    var parent_id2 = jObject2["parent_id"].ToString();
                    category.parent_id = Convert.ToInt32(parent_id2);

                }
                _context.Add(category);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Добавляется одна запись, а потом появляется ошибка:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Не могу понять, где ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку, не создавал внутри циклы новую запись.

```
category = new Categories();
```

Поэтому EF и пыталось каждый раз вставить один и тот же ID. Рабочий Контроллер выглядит так:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Categories category)
        {

            string str;
            using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
            {
                str = http.GetStringAsync("https://......./export/v2/?format=json&city=msk").Result;
            }

            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(str);
            var allUid = jObject["catalog"]["categories"].Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();
            foreach (var catg in allUid)
            {
                category = new Categories();

                JObject jObject2 = JObject.Parse(catg);

                var id2 = jObject2["id"].ToString();
                category.BravoId = Convert.ToInt32(id2);
                category.Name = jObject2["name"].ToString();

                if (jObject2["parent_id"] == null)
                {
                    category.parent_id = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    var parent_id2 = jObject2["parent_id"].ToString();
                    category.parent_id = Convert.ToInt32(parent_id2);

                }
                _context.Add(category);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```